# Getting "The security ID structure is invalid" while setting AD flag

Tags: c++, active-directory, dns

This is the same issue as in this thread: [Security ID Structure Invalid , Getting this error when setting the new SecurityDescriptor for AD user properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946150) but I am using C++ instead of .Net.

I want to set the flag "User Cannot Change Password" for an Active Directory account. I am using [this code from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but get an error

> The security ID structure is invalid.

This happens in the method `SetUserCannotChangePassword()` at this line:

```
//update the security descriptor property
hr = pads->Put(sbstrSecDesc, svar);
```

**This error only happens when I test this from a computer that is not in the same domain as the user I want to set the AD flag. If I run my app on the same domain as I modify everything works fine.**

Regarding this error code [I found this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948502/en-us). The advice of opening the ports for LSA did not work - I deactivated the firewalls but that did not fix the problem.

And I only have that problem with setting this flag. Other flags as "UserMustChangePassword" are no problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this solves your problem, as the issue is most likely some kind of bug in the Microsoft framework.

You refer that this bug only happens if you are executing this on a computer/user outside the domain you are currently changing, so you might try to establish a trusted connection to the Domain Server before executing your application.
This may be done in many different ways, but the easiest is to mount the IPC$ hidden share on the domain controller as a Domain Admin. Just execute this on the command prompt:

```
NET USE \\<DOMAIN-CONTROLER>\IPC$ /user:<DOMAIN-NAME>\<Domain-admin-user> <domain-admin-user-password>
```

Again, it may or may not solve your problem, but it's worth a shot :)

Comment: I don't believe it. That worked! I had to leave the password to make the command work. Then I had to type it in the console and after that setting the flag worked. Now I only have to think about doing this in my C++ app programmically.

Comment: Strange behaviors require strange resolutions :) Glad I could help. To map a network drive programatically you could use WNetAddConnection2 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413(v=vs.85).aspx). There are several example projects that use it. I assume that using it to map the IPC$ should be similar.

Answer (score 2):

I could not provide the solution of your problem now, but after I read another answer I decide to write some comments as the answer to have more place. I am sure that the origin of problem is the usage of [LookupAccountSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function or [LookupAccountName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) internally by. So you get an error. I find strange that the error `ERROR_INVALID_SID` (1337) error: "The security ID structure is invalid." is documented only in some API like [ConvertStringSidToSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [ConvertSidToStringSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [AddAccessAllowedAce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [AddAccessAllowedAceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and some other which should be not used in the code which you describe.

If one uses `LookupAccountName` for example to get SID of some account one can set `lpSystemName` parameter. It can be very important if one need to resolve the name from the domain to which no direct trust exist from the domain to which the computer belongs. For example if you have one master domain and two resource domains and you try to resolve an account from one resource domain on the computer from another resource domain. In the case the usage of NULL as the `lpSystemName` will fail, but in case of usage of any server from the master domain as the `lpSystemName`, for example a domain controller of the master domain, you will be able to resolve *any* account from any domains.

In the case any "opening the ports for LSA" will really not work. To be able really help you I need to know the syntax of `pwszUserDN` which you use in `ADsOpenObject` or in `SetUserCannotChangePassword`. There are some possibilities which you can use in the [Binding String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (see also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). I hope that you can solve the problem if you would change the syntax. For example you can try to specify the server explicitly. For example you can use

```
LDAP://server01/CN=Jeff Smith,CN=users,DC=fabrikam,DC=com
```

or

```
LDAP://domain2.fabrikam.com/CN=Users,DC=domain2,DC=fabrikam,DC=com
```

instead of

```
LDAP://CN=Jeff Smith,CN=users,DC=fabrikam,DC=com
```

Comment: That is actually a really good suggestion. I will look into it and report back.

Comment: @juergend: Do you have any results in the tests?

Comment: @juergend: Schade... In such questions you should better always describe exactly the AD structure and with the trusts (and its directions) and your restrictions. I know many ways how you can implement what you want, but I don't understand your environment. For example you can use [NetUserSetInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370659(v=vs.85).aspx) level 1 or 1008 to set `UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE` flag (0x0040). You can first read user settings with `NetUserGetInfo` modify and set back with `NetUserSetInfo`. As the `servername` you can use DC of destination domain.

Comment: The AD structure differs totally. It depends on my customer. bpatrao's solution worked. Thanks for your great efforts.

Comment: @juergend: I'm glad to hear, that the problem is solved. You wrote in your question: "The advice of opening the ports for LSA did not work". `Net use \\<DOMAIN-CONTROLER>\IPC$ ...` just do this. So your original information was incorrect. The problem here will be that you don't know **which domain controller will be used** in `ADsOpenObject` and later in `hr = pads->Put(sbstrSecDesc, svar);`. So you have to use *the same* `<DOMAIN-CONTROLER>` in LDAP Path: `LDAP://<DOMAIN-CONTROLER>/...`.

Comment: @juergend: By the way you can use [WNetAddConnection2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413(v=vs.85).aspx) or [NetUseAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370645(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of `net.exe`. It can be also required to *close* existing connection (with respect of `WNetCancelConnection2` for example) to  the destination server *before* you will be able to establish new connection.